# Macbook Pro does not recognize 2 8Gb RAM upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have a 13-inch Macbook Pro (mid-2011, running High Sierra 10.13.6), boot ROM MBP91.00D3.BOC. Successfully replaced HDD with SSD. Wanted to upgrade RAM to 16Gb using 2 8Gb DDR3 A-Tech PC3-10600-DIM 1333MHz. When both 8Gb sticks are installed, start-up loop occurs. With 1 2Gb (OEM) stick and 1 8Gb (A-Tech) stick installed, boots perfectly. Have switched out one 8Gb stick for other; boots perfectly. System recognizes 10Gb installed. How can I get system to recognize **both** 8Gb sticks?